# Flask db Database Table Issue unexpected keyword argument when inserting?

Tags: python, flask

I added a table named Payments to my Flask application, but when I tried to insert data into the new table I received the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'orderid'
```

when insert into the new payments table like so:

```
paymentdb = Payments(orderid=orderid, amount=amount, currency=currency, status="pending", wallet=response["address"], userid=current_user.id)
```

Even though I confirmed that all function inputs were correct, there seems to be an issue with my db/db structure. It is also strange to note that my new table is not displayed when using `flask db edit`. However, I can see the new table in my db file when I open it with VSCode. I also receive an error message stating that the table "users" already exists when I use `flask db upgrade`.

Here is the code from my `models.py` file:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from flask_login import UserMixin
from src import bcrypt, db,app

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    balance = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    key = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    def __init__(self, email, password, key, is_admin=False, balance=0.0):
        self.email = email
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)
        self.key = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(key)
        self.created_on = datetime.now()
        self.is_admin = is_admin
        self.balance = 0.0

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<email {self.email}>"

class Payments(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "payments"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    orderid = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=False)
    userid = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    amount = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    amount_usd = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    merchant_amount = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    currency= db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    wallet = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    
    def __init__(self, userid, amount, currency, status):
        self.userid = userid
        self.amount = amount
        self.currency = currency
        self.status = status
        self.created_on = datetime.now()
        self.wallet = response["address"]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<orderid {self.orderid}>"

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a Flask problem, but simply a mistake in how the class was constructed:

```
class Payments(db.Model):
    ...
    def __init__(self, userid, amount, currency, status):
```

The constructor for Payments doesn't accept an `orderid` argument. Perhaps you added the field but forgot to update the constructor?

```
class Payments(db.Model):
    ...
    def __init__(self, orderid, userid, amount, currency, status):
        self.orderid = orderid
        ...
```

---

I also noted another possible problem in the User constructor:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    ...
    def __init__(self, email, password, key, is_admin=False, balance=0.0):
        ...
        self.balance = 0.0
```

The balance is set to 0 regardless of the value passed in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you I just noticed this after posting haha. But one thing I don't understand is, why is flask db edit not working? It doesn't display the current DB, only a time where there was only the users table. I'm trying to look at the data in my new table. Also db upgrade gives me an error of (users table already exists)

Comment: Try to run the migrations manually or with verbose mode, to see what version it *thinks* the database is in, and to what version it's trying to bring it up to. But other than that I cannot help much.